# Using lodash not able to validate selected date

Tags: javascript, lodash

I try to validate selected date from angularjs weather date is selected or not. So for this i use lodash.isEmpty it returns empty but the date is selected.

```
 else if(lodash.isEmpty(exchangeRate.validTo)){
        console.log(exchangeRate.validTo);
        $scope.errorvalidTo = 'invalid'
    }
```

i have selected date but it always says empty

Comment: lodash `isEmpty` check if passed `object` or `array` is null. and it seems like you are passing string. Try using `isNull`

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isNull

Comment: Alternatively have a look at lodash's `isNil`, which will check for `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, _.isEmpty(new Date()) will always return true, because `Object.keys(new Date()).length === 0`. If you look at the source code of the isEmpty func : you can see this:

```
      ...
      for (var key in value) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(value, key)) {
         return false;
        }
      }
     return true;
```

A Date object has no key/values so it'll return true.

use `!_.isDate(...)` could be a better idea

Answer (score 0):

you can use validate.js isEmpty as an alternative

https://validatejs.org/#utilities-is-empty